# What does "wandering about" mean?

Tags: intransitive-preposition

[In a TV show I am watching, I just came across a strange expression :](https://www.facebook.com/DW50thZone/posts/677409762292657)

> [...] you're just wandering **about**.

I don't understand at all. What is the *about* for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an intransitive preposition (or in traditional grammar, an adverb) which indicates where the subject is wandering.  Here's how [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about?showCookiePolicy=true) defines it:

> here and there; from place to place; in no particular direction   ⇒ walk about to keep warm

It doesn't change the meaning of *wander* very much, but it's a common collocation and it sounds more natural to add it than leave it out.  It emphasizes the lack of a particular destination.

*Wander around* is a similar phrase which is a little bit less formal.